# Intersection of half-planes

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, computational-geometry

I need to prove the following:

> Let $H$ be a finite set of at least three half-planes. We call a
> half-plane $h ∈ H$ redundant if it does not contribute an edge to
> $∩H$. Prove that for any redundant half-plane $h ∈ H$ there are two
> half-planes $h ′ , h′′ ∈ H$ such that $ h ′ ∩ h ′′ ⊂ h.$

What I can tell for sure, Is that $∩H$ Must be above the line that defines the half plane $h$.
If that Is the case then the big intersection $∩H$ Is contained in $h$, But I don't know how to go further with this.

Any help will be appericiated, Thanks!

Comment: (1) Are you talking about half-planes in the Plane or in Space? Because you talk of "the line that defines the half plane", I'm guessing the former, but you need to make that explicit. (2) Consider $$H = \bigg\{\{(x,y):x \ge 0\}, \{(x,y):x \ge 1\}, \{(x,y):x \le -1\}\bigg\}$$ This case avoids your logic, but still fulfills the condition (can you see why)?

Comment: Actually, you can prove this whether $h$ is redundant or not. Let $h'$ be any other half-plane, and let $h''$ be $h$. Then $h' \cap h'' = h' \cap h \subset h$.  And if you say that $h'$ and $h''$ are meant to be distinct from $h$, then the statement is obviously false, as the example I gave above is one of many counter-examples.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - I think the condition $\cap H \neq \emptyset$ should be added to the OP question.

Comment: @HEKTO - but neither you nor I know what the actual problem is, only Guy Berkovitz does. I've pointed out some issues. This is what comments are for. Until they choose to clarify, those issues remain.